# Why when reporting the number of files counter in backgroundworker progresschanged event the text is blinking?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is how I'm reporting to the backgroundworker

```
private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension,string textToSearch)
        {
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            int numberofdirs = 0;
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
                int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
                if (var == 1)
                {
                    string filename = filePaths[i];
                    numberoffiles ++;
                    prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = filename, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                numberofdirs ++;
                prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report3 = numberofdirs.ToString() });
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
            }
        }

        public class MyProgress
        {
            public string Report1 { get; set; }
            public string Report2 { get; set; }
            public string Report3 { get; set; }
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In the dowork event and progresschanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _stopwatch.Restart();
            DirSearch(@"d:\c-sharp", "*.cs", "Form1");
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyProgress> mypro = e.UserState as List<MyProgress>;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro[0].Report1);
            label3.Text = mypro[0].Report2;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label1.Text = mypro[0].Report3;
            label1.Visible = true;
        }
```

The problem is with `label1.Text` in the `ProgressChanged` event I see the text on/off like blinking most of the time I don't event see the text at all.

I want to report to `label1` the number of searched directories from inside the DirSearch method.

Comment: If I had to guess you're changing it too fast.  Update it in increments of ... uh, N / 100, where N is the total number of directories to be searched.  And don't get into the trap where you're trying to show the user progress for an operation that takes less than a second to complete.  New programmers do that to themselves all the time, and it's a huge waste.

Comment: You are updating the UI as fast as the background worker can update its progress. This is happening so quickly the UI is basically a blur and/or blank.  Update the UI based on a timer or only update after so many updates.

Comment: But if i'm deleting the directories reportprogress and only report the files and files count it's working perfect. The problem started when i added the directories reportprogress part. I think something wrong with making a new instance for MyProgress class in two places.

Comment: Ok the solution not sure if it's a good way but it's working in my case i just invoke label1 in the DirSearch method i'm not reporting the variable numberofdirs to the progresschanged event i'm just doing label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString(); }); and it's all working now smooth.